# Ruby URL先のページが存在するか

Tags: ruby

以下のようなクエリのあるURLついて。

**http://blog.nogizaka46.com/karin.itou/?d=20180512**
例えば、クエリ(パラメータ？)を"?d=20180512"としたとき、挙動としては"?d=20180512"に対応したページが開かれます。
次に、"?d=20180000"などの存在しない値を入力した場合、**http://blog.nogizaka46.com/karin.itou/**ここにリダイレクトされます。

このようなWEBサイトがあるとき、リダイレクトされる(ページが存在しない)場合はfalse, リダイレクトされない(ページが存在する)場合はtrueを返すメソッドを作りたいです。

そこで、下記のようなコードを作成しました。

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def url_exist?(uri)
  agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
  begin
    url = URI.parse(uri)
    Net::HTTP.new(url.host).get(url.path, {"User-Agent": agent})
  rescue
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end

puts url_exist?("http://blog.nogizaka46.com/karin.itou/?d=20180512")
puts url_exist?("http://blog.nogizaka46.com/karin.itou/?d=20180000")
```

これだと、"?d=~"の値がどんなものでも、trueが返ってきてしまいました。
リダイレクトした先のURLを取得する['location']も試してみたのですが、中身は空となってしまいます。

どうにかして、リダイレクト先のURLを取得するか、falseが取得できるようにしたいです。
どのようにすればいいでしょうか？

お知恵をお貸しいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問に掲載のコードを実行するとどちらの場合も `200 OK` が返されるでしょう。なぜなら、`get(url.path)`としているため実際のリクエストには指定のURLの`?`以降のクエリは含まれていないためです。(その為どちらも同じページをリクエストしています)

```
Net::HTTP.new(url.host).get(url.path)
```

を

```
Net::HTTP.new(url.host).get(url.request_uri)
```

で置き換えることでその問題は解決できるかと思います。

（もちろんどちらの場合も例外は投げられないのでそこだけ変えても意図した動作にはならないと思いますが、問題はそこのようです。）

Comment: ありがとうございます！望んだ結果が出力されました！
getの引数など、まだまだ理解不足な部分があり申し訳ありません。。
大変勉強になりました！